# Wordpress website isn't recognising increase in max filesize upload

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I've increased (from 10M to 20M):

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 25M
```

Found in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

I've increased (from 10M to 20M):

```
http {
#...
    client_max_body_size 20m;
#...
}
```

Found in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

I've restarted using the commands:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

And still wordpress isn't recognising change! I recently created a child theme, would that have anything to do with it?

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 server with Nginx and php. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Add this to top of `wp-config.php` `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '25M');`

Comment: Found the issue, there was a problem with restarting the php, thank you for taking the time to answer :)